# Fetch throws "Network request failed" in React-Native 0.14

Tags: android, localhost, fetch, react-native

Fetch is throwing a `Network request failed` error when I try to make a request to a local server in the Android emulator. I'm pretty sure the request isn't getting out of the app.

I've checked and double checked the request headers and target URL, all correct (Hitting the right URL and specifying `Content-Type` and `Accept`). I tried disabling CORS on my local server, no effect. 
I'm using digits in my app and digits is able to make contact with its server outside the app and return authorization, so I'm think something is going on with React-Native.

I've tried manipulating the app permissions, but no dice, it only needs the `android.permissions.INTERNET` heading in the manifest.

Any ideas on how to move forward, either a quick fix or something I've overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, the problem was that the android emulator runs in a VM.  I was trying to hit localhost, which was pointing at the VM, so I needed to specify my ip or 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: Awesome, if love to see the digits integration when ready. I'm thinking of trying it to, do a ask tips welcome

Comment: Here's our integration in case anyone is looking for an example. https://github.com/fixt/react-native-digits